# How to share code across python docker services inside monorepo

Tags: python, docker, containers, monorepo

I have common python code I want to share across services. I currently have a modular monolith but I would like to break it out into a few independent containers.

Ideally the layout would look like the following:

```
/project
    /common
    /service-a
    /service-b
```

I am looking to avoid having to version and publish the `common` code, since I am working with a monorepo it feels like that would be loosing the benefits.

Answer (score -2):

well, if your using git
you can create a `.dockerignore` file. to ignore the folders and files

```
**/common
```

this should do the trick (it works for me)
[sorry, I mistyped]

Comment: In what way does that solve anything? They don't want to ignore the code and exclude it from git.

Comment: well, when I usually use docker when I add a .gitignore file it usually docker ignores it.

Comment: Nothing in this question is about ignoring anything, it is about how to bundle / build an application / deployable.

Comment: oh wait, the file should be .dockerignore, so the it would be excluded in builds

Comment: Does not change anything, OP does not want to exclude / ignore anything.

Comment: the OP is trying to not publish or version the `/common` folder, so they have to ignore it/exclude it from builds

Comment: No, they want to include it in both deployed python applications. Not publishing a version is referring to not separately packing and distributing this folder as a library the other applications then depend on. This cannot be solved by ignoring anything, this can only be solved by properly setting up packages and deployment scripts.

Comment: Oh... ok, well then I'm stumped on how to execute this. Do you know a way of doing this?